# React giving "survey" not defined when survey.onComplete is outside of class

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This code was not using a class with export when I found it.  Seems the open source is instead using it to render as js file and have div id display the content.  I prefer to not do that for a lot of reasons with my codebase

It does not like `survey.onComplete`  and `surver.data` etc.. as those are outside the class, but i'm a bit new to React so I'm trying to figure out how to make this work.  Perhaps some survey object?

Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Survey from "survey-react";
import "survey-react/survey.css";


var surveyValueChanged = function (sender, options) {
    var el = document.getElementById(options.name);
    if (el) {
        el.value = options.value;
    }
};

var json = {
    questions: [
        {
            type: "text",
            name: "name",
            title: "Your name:"
        }, {
            type: "text",
            name: "email",
            title: "Your e-mail"
        }, {
            type: "checkbox",
            name: "car",
            title: "What car are you driving?",
            isRequired: true,
            colCount: 4,
            choices: [
                "None",
                "Ford",
                "Vauxhall",
                "Volkswagen",
                "Nissan",
                "Audi",
                "Mercedes-Benz",
                "BMW",
                "Peugeot",
                "Toyota",
                "Citroen"
            ]
        }
    ]
};


window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);


survey
    .onComplete
    .add(function (result) {
        document
            .querySelector('#surveyResult')
            .textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 3);
    });

survey.data = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@nobody.com',
    car: ['Ford']
};

// ReactDOM.render(
//     <Survey.Survey model={survey} 
//     onValueChanged={surveyValueChanged}/>, 
//     document.getElementById("surveyElement"));

class SurveyTest extends React.Component {

    render()
    {
        var survey = new Survey.Model();

        return(

        <Survey.Survey model={survey} 
        onValueChanged={surveyValueChanged}/>

        )
    }
}

export default SurveyTest;
```

**Notice what I commented out is what the codebase used.**  I changed to be a class that I export, but then I end up with problems.

Comment: Ok, I was getting further with changing `window.survey` to  `var survey` , but then nothing displays and if I add `componentDidMount(){`
        `surveyValueChanged();`
    `}`  it does not like that function call.